# dynamically create input type='text' boxes then add values from each into Backbone.js array

Tags: javascript, arrays, dynamic, backbone.js, input

I was wondering how to create a number of text boxes based on a type='number' box...so as soon as someone adds 1 to the number box, another text box field would be appended to the backbone.js view...and then once someone enters values into those textboxes, add each value to a spot in a backbone model array. Here is some of the code:

```
    <label for='choices'># Choices for Students</label>
    <input type='number' name='choices' step=1 />

    initialize: function(opts) {
    this.model = new QuestionCreateModel({
        mode: null,
        choices: ['A', 'B', 'C'],
        Question: "Question goes here",
        MaxChoices: 0,
        MinChoices: 0,
        WordLimit: 0,
        CharLimit: 0,
    }),
```

as you can kind of see, I want to take that input type='number' and then load the text boxes so I can assign values to the choices array in the Backbone model.

Thanks for the help!

-Stu

Answer (score 0):

Your code is insufficient I think.

First, you need a collection and a model.

then you create your view, which listens to add, remove, change or reset events of the collection. If you do that, your view will handle those events and renders whatever you say it should render.

```
myView = Backbone.View.extend({
   initialize : function() {
       this.collection = this.options.collection || new myCollection();
       this.collection.on("add remove reset change", this.render, this)
   },
   events : {
       "change [type='number']" : "numberChanged"
   },
   numberChanged : function(ev) {
       var $el = $(ev.target || ev.srcElement);
       var model = $el.data("model");
       model.set("selectedChoice", $el.val());
   },
   render : function() {
       this.$el.empty();
       this.collection.each(function(model) {
           $("<yourinput>").data("model", model)
               .appendTo(this.$el);
       }, this);
   }
});
```

Now your Model and Collection

```
var myModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
   initialize : function() {
      this.on("change:selectedChoice", this.onChoiceChanged, this);
   },
   onChoiceChanged : function(model,value) {
      // from here you know, that a value was selected, you now
      // can say the collection, it should create a new model
      if (this.collection) this.collection.push();
      // this will trigger a "add" event and your "view" will react and rerender.
   }
});

var myCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
   model : myModel
});
```